# How to browse or extract an old (.db) file

Tags: c#, .net, database

i have an old (.db) database file and i need to extract the contents of it or to use it with a c# application but i dont know which software to use please help me 
check this link that lists the db file types.

http://www.file-extensions.org/search/?searchstring=db&searchtype=2

thank you

Comment: A .db file can be many, many different things. What is the file's origin? Take a peek inside with a text editor and look for clues.

Comment: How old?  Have you looked at the binary contents what to the first 100 bytes look like?

Comment: its a database and it runs under DOS
the first 100 bytes contain some symbols and i dont know what is the meaning of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, checking the link in your question, I could browse through the apps that were related to DB extension. And after a quick analysis, I think dBASE will to what you need.

http://www.file-extensions.org/dbase-file-extensions

It allows you to open, edit, save and convert to another extension that might suits you better.

I guess that MS Access and SQLite can do the same thing dBASE will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `*.db` has been used by *many* programs.

Using any Unixoid system (Linux, BSD, MacOS) you can use the `file(1)` utility to get the program which probably created that file. Using this information you can then ask for more *specific* help here.

As an example for *my* `*.db` files and the output of `file`:

```
/etc/libgda-4.0/sales_test.db:  SQLite 3.x database
/home/XXX/.mozilla/firefox/cert8.db:   Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native 
/var/cache/man/cs/index.db: GNU dbm 1.x or ndbm database,
```